# Verifying Fourier series of antiderivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The function is $f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&-\pi\leq x \leq 0\\x,&0<x\leq \pi\end{cases}$.

The Fourier series of the function is: $$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\pi}{2})+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n-1}{\pi n^{2}}\cos (nx)+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin (nx)$$
Since the function can be integrated termwise, the Fourier series for the antiderivative $\int_{-\pi}^xf(x) \,dx$ is:
$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\pi}{2})(x+\pi)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{(-1)^n-1}{\pi n^{2}}\sin (nx)+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}(\cos (nx)-(-1)^n)\right)$$
The antiderivative of the function is $F(x)=\begin{cases}0,&-\pi\leq x \leq 0\\\frac{x^2}{2},&0<x\leq \pi\end{cases}$. The Fourier series of the antiderivative is:
$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\pi^2}{6})+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\left(\left(\frac{(-1)^n-1}{\pi n^{2}}-(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sin (nx)+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\cos (nx)\right)$$

Where I am missing? Why I am having wrong answer. Even if I did some mistakes in calculations, what's with $x$ term obtained in piece wise integration.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The free term is $a_0/2 = \int_0^\pi x \, dx/(2 \pi) \neq \pi/8$. You cannot take $1/n$ outside of the sum over $n$. $x$ and $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/n^2$ obtained after the integration are correct, but they're not in Fourier series form. $\pi/2$ in the last Fourier series should be $(-1)^n \pi/2$. The free term in the last Fourier series is also incorrect.

Comment: I've edited now. Thank you. But if it is not if fourier series form, how to verify it? It can change upto a constant, how the term $x$ appear.

Comment: Now the two formulas are in agreement (since we're evaluating a definite integral, there isn't an arbitrary constant of integration). To verify that the formulas do in fact match, subtract $\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^{2 n}/n^2 = \pi^2/6$ from the free term and expand $x$ into a Fourier series (on $(-\pi, \pi)$): $x = 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty ((-1)^{n - 1}/n) \sin n x$.

Comment: yeah. make sense. But what about the extra term with $\cos (nx)$?

Comment: I don't follow. I see $((-1)^n/n^2) \cos n x$ in both formulas and $-(-1)^{2 n}/n^2$ in the first formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments, What you have is:
$$\frac{\pi}{4}x+\frac{\pi^2}{4}+\sum \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{(-1)^n-1}{\pi n^2}\sin(nx)+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cos(nx)\right)-\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$$
The Fourier expansion of $x$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$ is $x=-2\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin (nx)$ and using the fact that $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. It is obttained that,
$$\frac{\pi}{4}\left(-2\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin (nx)\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{4}+\sum \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{(-1)^n-1}{\pi n^2}\sin(nx)+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cos(nx)\right)-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
$$\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\sum\frac{1}{n} \left(\left(\frac{(-1)^n-1}{\pi n^2}-(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sin(nx)+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cos(nx)\right)$$
Now both results conicides.